# Reading pixel values of a 16x16 image with SDL

Tags: c++, sdl-image

I use SDL_image to load an image to a `SDL_Surface`. How can I get all this data into a `vector <int> pixels`?

I have tried:

```
Uint32 GetPixel(SDL_Surface *img, int x, int y) {
SDL_LockSurface(img);

//Convert the pixels to 32 bit
Uint32 *pixels = (Uint32 *)img->pixels;

//Get the requested pixel
return pixels[(y * img->w) + x];

SDL_LockSurface(img);
}
```

And I wonder why I get strange results...
with a 3x3 Image with a black pixel in the center i get:

```
[0] (0, 0): 255, 255, 255
[1] (0, 1): 255, 255, 255
[2] (0, 2): 255, 255, 255
[3] (1, 0): 255, 255, 255
[4] (1, 1): 255, 0, 0               //WHY IS THIS NOT 0,0,0?
[5] (1, 2): 255, 255, 255
[6] (2, 0): 255, 255, 255
[7] (2, 1): 255, 255, 255
[8] (2, 2): 255, 255, 255
```

Comment: I want pixel[0][0] to go to index 0. [0][1] in index 1, and [1][0] into 16 visa versa.. I need the data for a Neural Network

Comment: You can click [edit] to clarify your question.

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/62705/how-do-i-access-the-pixels-of-an-sdl-2-texture

Comment: Code after your return statement won't execute.  You probably want to copy the value to a temporary value and then unlock the surface before returning the temporary value.

Comment: You need to take the `pitch` value in account when reading pixels.

Comment: Check the pixel format.  If you loaded a bmp file it's probably 24bpp, so indexing the way you are is incorrect.  A short complete example showing how you create the surface would help quite a bit.

Comment: thank you, i completly overlooked that. i'll fix my return